# Best data length for storing OAuth tokens

Tags: mysql, database, oauth, types, token

I want to write a mysql database schema for storing OAuth access tokens which is sufficiently generic so that it is capable for supporting any provider that complies with the OAuth standard.

What would be a sensible data length to achieve this aim and why? As far as I can see, no maximum length is enforced by the standard and I don't want to have to change my column length whenever I decide to support a new provider that happens to use larger tokens.

If this is not practical/possible, what would be a sensible length for supporting the more popular OAuth providers and why?

**CHOSEN SOLUTION**

Using a data type with an undefined length seems to be the only sufficiently generic option for my case.

Comment: Your question is based on the faulty assumption that it is always advantageous to choose a length that is as small as possible.  This is not true for every database.  For example, in PostGreSQL, the unlimited length `text` type is just as efficient as a fixed size `char`.

Comment: Fair enough. I have changed the question so it is asking specifically about a mysql implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `text` data type for this if you don't know the exact length.